# Which keys are returned by ToAscii as a two characters length string?

Tags: windows, winapi

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms646316(v=vs.85).aspx), there's the possibility that ToAscii function returns a two characters length string.

> ```
> int WINAPI ToAscii(
>   _In_           UINT   uVirtKey,
>   _In_           UINT   uScanCode,
>   _In_opt_ const BYTE   *lpKeyState,
>   _Out_          LPWORD lpChar,
>   _In_           UINT   uFlags
> );
> ```
>
> If the specified key is a dead key, the return value is negative.
>   Otherwise, it is one of the following values.
>
> 0 - The specified virtual key has no translation for the current state
>   of the keyboard.
>
> 1 - One character was copied to the buffer.
>
> 2 - Two
>   characters were copied to the buffer. This usually happens when a
>   dead-key character (accent or diacritic) stored in the keyboard layout
>   cannot be composed with the specified virtual key to form a single
>   character.

It says "...a dead-key character (accent or diacritic)..." but I didn't find one. Which keys are these who causes ToAscii returning 2?
Could someone tell me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dead keys are characters like `'`, `"`, `` ` ``, and `^`. In some keyboard layouts (e.g. US-International), pressing <kbd>'</kbd> by itself does not produce a character. You must press another key after that:

- <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> produces `'`
- <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> produces `á`
- <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> produces `'t` (because `t` with acute accent does not exist)

I guess the last one is the example they mean.

Comment: I set up a little test using US-International keyboard and each time I pass 222 (Which is the keycode for '
), ToAscii returns a 2 characters length string ('').